# Conditional construct not working in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I an a newbie in python and I want to use my regex in `re.sub`. I tried it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/InljCc/1) and it works. Somehow when I tried to use it on my python (version 3.6) it doesn't work properly. I get the following warning

> bad character in group name '?=[^\t]*' at position 5

This is my code:

```
re = r"(?(?=[^\t]*)([\t]+))";
str = 'a            bold, italic,           teletype';
subst = ',';

result = re.sub($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Select `python` in the left pannel on Regex101.

Comment: I did it, but still it makes warning.

Comment: Python doesn't use `$` characters for variables and slashes for regular expressions. Are you sure that what you have posted can actually be executed?

Comment: Are you just trying to replace tabs with commas? Why do you need a positive lookahead? What is the first ? supposed to do?

Comment: I need to replace just first tabs. After next word it should not supposed to replace.

Comment: You should not use `re` as the pattern variable name. At least. Same with `str`.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use lookarounds in conditional constructs in a Python `re`. Only capturing group IDs to test if the previous group matched.

Comment: so you'd just like to replace the tabs between 'a' and 'bold'?

Comment: yes, I want to replace just between 'a' and 'bold'. But between "bold" and "italic" can be also tabs or spaces. "a\t\t\tbold, italic, \t \t \tteletype"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use lookarounds in conditional constructs in a Python `re`. Only capturing group IDs to test if the previous group matched.

> **`(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`**
>   Will try to match with `yes-pattern` if the group with given *id* or name exists, and with `no-pattern` if it doesn’t. `no-pattern` is optional and can be omitted.

The `(?(?=[^\t]*)([\t]+))` regex checks if there are 0+ chars other than tabs at the current location, and if yes, matches and captures 1 or more tabs. This makes no sense. If you want to match the first occurrence of 1 or more tabs, you may use `re.sub` with a mere `"\t+"` pattern and `count=1` argument.

```
import re
reg = "\t+";
s = 'a          bold, italic,           teletype';
result = re.sub(reg, ',', s, count=1);
print(result);
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7xnUPN)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do this:

```
import re

regex = r'(^\w*?[\t]+)'
s = 'a      bold, italic,           teletype'

def repl(match):
    s = match.group(0)
    return s.rstrip() + ', '

print(re.sub(regex,repl, s))
```

out

```
a, bold, italic,            teletype
```

Here we are capturing the beginning of the string through any tabs that may occur after the first word, and passing the match to a callable. The callable removes trailing tabs with `rstrip` and adds a trailing comma.

Note: if the first tab occurs after the first word, it's not replaced. i.e. `'a bold, italic,           teletype'` is left unchanged. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask u what is the reason to use rstrip() in this code? :)

Comment: see additional commentary in my answer.